# How to play Video in UIWebView but it will not open in native movie player?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, uiwebview, html5-video

I have to implement the functionality like http://www.ani-view.com/. i have to play video in UIWebView only but when you click on the video box on UIWebView it will open in Native movie Player (MPMoviePlayer) not in webview video box.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Video tag with this options

```
    <video id="player" class="video" width="80%" height="500px" webkit-playsinline controls autoplay>
<source src="ert.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```